# IBM Worklight 6.1 - NativePage.show callback not called if in offline mode

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

We recently changed our Worklight connection settings so that the app doesn't connect to the Worklight Server.

After this change, my code that shows the Native page (AppInit.js) no longer returns to the JavaScript callback function.

It seems that the Native page runs to the end, but my call to `WL.Logger.log('backFromNativeLoginPage');` does not get executed. It hangs on the last visible page until the phone goes to sleep mode and then resumed by a user, or if a user switches to the home screen and switches back to the app. After that, the callback code is executed.

I also noticed an entry in LogCat, which I didn't notice before:

> THREAD WARNING: exec() call to Logger.LOG blocked the main thread for
>   44ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool()

The only way I've gotten this to work properly is when I set `connectOnStartup` to `true`. I'm not sure why it's dependent on a connection to the server in oreder to return from a native page? Since connecting to the server is not an option for us, does anyone know if there's a workaround? Has anyone seen this before?

Here's my code:

**AppInit.js**

```
var showNativePage = function() {
    WL.NativePage.show('com.app.Login', function(data) {
       WL.Logger.log('backFromNativeLoginPage');  //Does not run if connectOnStartup=false
    }, {param: 'some value'});
};
```

**initOptions.js**

```
var wlInitOptions = {   
    connectOnStartup: false //setting this to true works
};

WLJSX.bind(window, 'load', function() {
    WL.Client.init(wlInitOptions);
});
```

**Login.java**

```
public class Login extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LoginWebViewClient client = new LoginWebViewClient(this);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.login);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(client);
        webView.loadUrl(url);
    }

    public void setAppDataAndReturn(HashMap<String, String> dataList) {
        Intent returnData = new Intent();

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> item : dataList.entrySet()) {
            returnData.putExtra(item.getKey(), item.getValue());
        }

        setResult(RESULT_OK, returnData);
        finish();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

After trying a number of suggestions, I came across some documentation on [Cordova events](http://blogs.telerik.com/appbuilder/posts/13-12-31/phonegap-apache-cordova-lifecycle-events), and following it, I finally got it to work by adding the following code to my AppInit.js file:

```
function wlEnvInit() {
    wlCommonInit();

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(info) {
        document.addEventListener("resume", function(e){ WL.Logger.log('Resume from native page.'); }, false);
    });
}
```

I'm not exactly sure why this works, but it seems that `WL.Logger.log()` statement is required, because the callback did not execute without it. If anyone could shed some light as to why it works this way, I'd be interested to know. Hope this 'workaround' helps someone who may have come across the same problem...

Comment: The sample project for NativePage does not connect to the Worlight Server and is working fine. I suggest that you compare the two. Also, it would be best if you could supply a working demo Worklight project (not generated android project or .apk, but the Worklight project), instead of code snippets at this point.

Comment: Thanks @IdanAdar. I did a comparison of the two projects, and tried to copy over some settings that were different, but that didn't seem to help. I did try a 'workaround', which seemed to get the callback to execute. (see update in original post). Thanks for your help!

Comment: Not sure why you would need that, because once the app reaches in its initializaton to wlCommonInit, this means that internally device.ready has already been called successfully.

Comment: The logcat warning can be safely ignored.

Answer (score 2):

I see you have the following code in initOptions.js:

```
WLJSX.bind(window, 'load', function() {
    WL.Client.init(wlInitOptions);
});
```

This results in a call to `WL.Client.init` function on the browser (or webview, in hybrid apps) `load` event.  Some executable code under the code path triggered by `WL.Client.init` depends on Cordova being fully initialized.  The `connectOnStartup: true` directive triggers a code path that depends on Cordova having already been fully initialized.  Full Cordova initialization is indicated by the `deviceready` event.

**You are triggering `WL.Client.init` before the `deviceready` event.  Hence you see unexpected behavior.**

I strongly suggest removing the `load` event bind and callback code, and placing all of your initialization code in `wlCommonInit` or `wlEnvInit`, which are triggered on the `deviceready` event.  You **do not** need to explicitly listen for `deviceready` in your code.